# Center citation for image source

Tags: citing, rmarkdown

I display a image in my rmarkdown file and want to give also source for that. Source is one book and it must be @assael1987consumer but when I converted this to pdf I get output as @assael1987consumer not the right form. How can give citation between \begin and \end or is there any other way to give source to image ?

```
![Customer behaviour categories](..\image.png) 
\begin{center}
assael1987consumer
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.